# pyorient : How to create a vertex using record_create

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

```
class Person(Node):
    id = String(unique = True)
    name = String()
```

I tried the following way to create a Person node. But it's not working.

```
person = {
    'Person' : Person(name='Record', id = 1004).__dict__
}
client.record_create(0, person)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "command" statement:

[image]

Comment: raw queries.. :\

Comment: why do you want to avoid these?

Comment: hard to maintain raw queries